# Class() takes no arguments

Tags: python

Вот такой код. Ошибка Library1() takes no arguments
В толк не возьму где косяк, **Init** уже трижды переписывал

```
class Library1(object):
    global PING,PONG,BUSY,FORWARD, BACKWARD,ISTANT,SOURCE,EMPTY,FULL, IN, OUT
    global LYB
    pool=[]   
    messages=[]
    
    def __Init__(self, book1):
        print("!!!!")       
        self.pool=[]
        self.pool+=book1.split("")
        self.pool+=book1.split(".")
        self.pool+=book1.split(",")
        self.pool+=book1.split("?")
        self.pool+=book1.split("-")
        self.pool+=book1.split("/")
        self.messages+=[book]
        print("????")
        print(str(self.pool))
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pool)
    
my_lyb=Library1("pew")
print(my_lyb)
```

Comment: откуда заглавные буквы в названии метода init?

Comment: и откуда эта манера объявлять глобальные переменные?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно ошибка здесь:

```
  def __Init__(self, book1)
```

C большой буквы init написан, первый раз такое вижу.